# Make a tab-delimited file containing information from a file and part of a filename

Tags: bash, awk, sed, command-line, csv

I have many files containing:

```
>c_000000000288
abcdefg

>c_000000000270
abcdefg

>c_000000000062
abcdefg

*Note: continues for hundreds of lines
```

The filenames are something like:

```
M07.compare.M010.info500.info2.1.txt
M07.compare.M010.info500.info2.2.txt
M07.compare.M010.info500.info2.3.txt
M07.compare.M010.info500.info2.word.txt
```

Note: I would like the code to work for different number ranges (e.g. 1-10 or 1-3) and include "word" at the same time.

I want the result to be a tab-delimited file containing something like:

```
c_000000000288   1
c_000000000270   1
c_000000000062   1
c_000000000258   2
c_000000000191   3
c_000000000188   3
c_000000003713   3
c_000000000179   3
c_000000000162   word
c_000000000097   word
```

I have tried to search many forums and have not been able to find a solution. So far, I have only been able to extract "name" into a tab-delimited file, but I have not figured out how to efficiently add the filename information.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sorry! I added more information.

Comment: Can you post the code you have written so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is:

```
shopt -s extglob
awk -v OFS='\t' '
FNR==1 { n=split(FILENAME,f,/\./); ext=f[n-1] }
sub(/^>/,""){ print $0, ext }
' M07.compare.M010.info500.info2.{{1..10},word}.txt
```